# C# How Should I Reflection and lambda Expression combined use

Tags: c#

```
public List<BaseInfo> GetBaseInfos(string PatientID)
        {
            PropertyInfo? info = typeof(BaseInfo).GetProperty(LabelConst.ID);
            if (info == null) throw new Exception("this Property is null"+ LabelConst.ID);

            return _serviceBase.QueryNoTracking<BaseInfo>(x => x.PatientID == PatientID).ToList();
        }
```

I have such a method,where the value of LabelConst.ID is "PatientID".

How should I do it to do something like

```
return _serviceBase.QueryNoTracking<BaseInfo>(x => x.{info} == PatientID).ToList(); //this info is "PatientID"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `PropertyInfo` object has a `GetValue()` method.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen But doesn't GetValue need an instance of `BaseInfo`, then (given it's not a static property)? The whole thing doesn't really make sense to me right now.

Comment: Dont we first need a source for the lambda ?

Comment: @Fildor I would try `x` as instance.